# Object's data member value not set

Tags: javascript, object

I am getting unexpected output after setting the value of data member. What is the rationale behind this behavior?

```
function studentClass(id, name) 
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.print = function() { 
        alert(id + ": " + name);
    }
}

var s = new studentClass(101, "Vijay");
s.print();     // 101, Vijay
alert(s.id);   // 101
alert(s.name); // Vijay

s.id = 102;
alert(s.id);  // 102 
s.print();    // 101, Vijay Why?
```

https://jsfiddle.net/00d1cvxL/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `alert(this.id + ": " + this.name);` in the `print` function.
Earlier it was displaying the arguments `id` and `name` that you passed to `studentClass`.